"database disk image is malformed" on dbinit
On a local server I tried airflow standalone to run Airflow but it throws:
root@SGS-001-G037:/home/mahdi# airflow standalone
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1910, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 58, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 53, in entrypoint
    StandaloneCommand().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/providers_configuration_loader.py", line 55, in wrapped_function
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 69, in run
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 179, in initialize_database
    db.initdb()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 79, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 752, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session, use_migration_files=use_migration_files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1641, in upgradedb
    _reserialize_dags(session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 895, in _reserialize_dags
    session.execute(delete(SerializedDagModel).execution_options(synchronize_session=False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1717, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1710, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 334, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1577, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1953, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2134, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1910, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) database disk image is malformed
[SQL: DELETE FROM serialized_dag]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)


had to run below to work again:
rm -r /root/airflow/airflow.db

